# Quotient ideals and localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> If $I$ is an irreducible ideal of a commutative ring with unit $A$, then the following are equivalent:
>
> $$(i) \text{ for every multiplicatively closed set }S\subset A \text{ containing }1\in A, \text{the contraction of }S^{-1}I \text{ equals }(I:a)\text{ for some }a\in S.$$
> $$(ii)\text{ the chain }(I:1)\subset(I:a)\subset(I:a^2)\subset\cdots\text{ is stationary for every }a\in A.$$

I've already proven that $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$, now I'm stuck with $(ii)\Rightarrow(i)$. Here's where I'm at:

Assume every such chain is stationary. From proposition $3.11$ from Atiyah-Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, we get:

$$(S^{-1}I)^c=\bigcup_{s\in S}(I:s)$$

The above union can be rewriten as $\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcup_{n=0}(I:s^n)$. Since $(I:1)\subset(I:s)\subset(I:s^2)\subset...$ is stationary for every $s\in S$, then $\bigcup_{n=0}(I:s^n)=(I:s^{n_s})$ for some $n_s\in\mathbb{N}$, so $\bigcup_{s\in S}(I:s)=\bigcup_{s\in S}(I:s^{n_s})$. Now I'm stuck trying to find $a\in A$ such that $\bigcup_{s\in S}(I:s^{n_s})=(I:a)$. I still can't see how the irreductibility of $I$ is supposed to come up.

Comment: This question is part of Exercise 3, Chapter 7 from Atiyah and Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*.

Comment: The case $S\cap I\ne\emptyset$ should be obvious. Suppose $S\cap I=\emptyset$ and show that $(S^{-1}I)^c=I$. If $sa\in I$ for some $s\in S$ then consider $n\ge 1$ such that $I:s^n=I:s^{n+1}=\cdots$. Note that $I=(I+(s^n))\cap(I:s^n)$, and by irreducibility of $I$ get $I=I:s^n$. Now conclude that $a\in I$.